# Configuration Xdebug using PhpStorm and WMware Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, phpstorm, xdebug, vmware

My PHP Xdebug doesn't work. Here is my setup and my configurations :
I have PC windows with PhpStorm IDE and I have a VM WMware (which is my server) with Ubuntu Linux and Apache 2.

I've followed the Xdebug documentation to install Xdebug 3.

The settings of PhpStorm are :

- checkbox "break at first line in PHP scripts" is checked and I put also several break points in the code
- Xdebug port: 9000, 9003 and "can accept external connections" is checked

The settings of Virtual Machine is :

- The IP `192.168.127.128` and my local website is on `192.168.127.128:57`
- the content of `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/20-xdebug.ini` is :

```ini
; Xdebug 3
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=1
```

- there is a 10-opcache.ini file but due to its name, this file is above 20-xdebug.ini

The settings of the web browser :

- Xdebug module is installed and I chose IDE key = PHPSTORM

Other infos :

- the result of the cmd :

```
php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

- I inspected the http request and in the header, there is the `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`

My test is :

- restart apache2
- click on the button telephone icon in PhpStorm to start listening
- go to `192.168.127.128:57/index.php` => the page is successfully displayed but no breakpoints is triggered
- I don't have any error message in PhpStorm

Comment: 1) *"xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1"* This should be the IP of the machine when PhpStorm is running (your host OS) as seen from the VM. it cannot be 127.0.0.1 (unless you are using some kind of SSH port forwarding or alike). Remember, it's Xdebug that connects to the client (IDE) and NOT other way around. 2) Enable Xdebug log and see what it has to say there. Where it tries to connect to and what the result is. 3) Show `xdebug_info()` output -- it will show your live config + any troubleshooting messages.

Comment: 4) It could also be your Windows Firewall. You need to make sure that PhpStorm can accept connections on Xdebug ports.

Comment: *"Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded"* You may be loading `xdebug.so` in more than one .ini file (check all config files for `zend_extension=` lines). It's not critical, but better avoid this and it could also mean that you may have different settings elsewhere; that's why #3 point is useful -- to check that you have the expected values.